# How can I dynamically create a component based on a prop or variable using React.createElement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 types of components, for example a `<Promo />` and an `<Announcement />`

One of my components maps over a list of items and creates either promos or announcements, how can I pass an ItemElement, rather than have to repeat the mapping based on an if statement.

**current implementation**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Promo from './Promo'
import Announcement from './Announcement'

class Demo extends Component {

  render() {
    const { ItemElement } = this.props
    let items = null

    if(ItemElement === 'Promo'){

      items = this.props.items.map((p, i) => (
        <Promo item={p} />
      ))

    } else if(ItemElement === 'Announcement') {

      items = this.props.items.map((a, i) => (
        <Announcement item={a} />
      ))
    }

    return (
      { items }
    )
  }
}
```

**desired implementation not working**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Promo from './Promo'
import Announcement from './Announcement'

class Demo extends Component {

  render() {
    // this would be 'Promo' or 'Announcement'
    const { ItemElement } = this.props 

    let items = this.props.items.map((p, i) => (
      <ItemElement item={p} />
    ))

    return (
      { items }
    )
  }
}
```

This works fine if I pass in say a `'div'` or `'a'` or `'span'` tag, but not for my own components?

Comment: This _should_ work fine. How are you trying to render this?

Comment: Also your `render()` method doesn't actually _return_ anything. You should probably have a `return (<div>{this.props.items.map(...)}</div>);` in there

Comment: @rossipedia sorry, it was just an example, I will update to show the full render method returning the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `render()` method needs to return a single element. Right now you're returning a javascript object with a single property: `items`. You need to contain those items in a top level element, either another Component, or a DOM element (`<div>` or `<span>` or the like).

As for passing a component in as a prop, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to do that:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {

  render() {
    // this would be 'Promo' or 'Announcement'
    const { ItemElement } = this.props 

    let items = this.props.items.map((p, i) => (
      <ItemElement item={p} />
    ))

    return <ul>{items}</ul>;
  }
}

class Promo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>Promo - {this.props.item}</li>; 
  }
}

class Announcement extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <li>Announcement - {this.props.item}</li>;
  }
}

const items = [
  "foo",
  "bar"
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo 
    ItemElement={Promo} // <- try changing this to {Announcement}
    items={items} 
  />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here's a jsbin demonstrating: http://jsbin.com/cakumex/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks for that, nice work. It wasn't an issue with the `render()` method needing to return a single element but something unrelated. That was just an issue with me simplifying the example and leaving out the container `<div />` accidentally. The tip on passing in the component as a prop rather than as a string was helpful and a better approach than passing it as a string.

Comment: To elaborate on my issue... the items were to be rendered in a swiper using the [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper) library, `<Demo />` component inits Swiper on `componentDidMount()`. Now, at the time the component is mounted the items are strangely not shown when I pass in the component as a prop. However this issue isn't present if I just specify `<Promo />` or `<Announcement />` instead of the prop `<ItemElement />`. It is a bit strange, maybe it is somewhat slower rendering when you pass in the component as a prop... I'm not sure?