# In ReactJS is it possible to dynamically choose the component to render?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render a specific ReactJS component, depending on a variable

When I do this, nothing is rendered.

Can someone suggest if this is even possible?

Please note this is not working code, it is a trimmed down representation of the concept I am trying to implement.

```
import React from 'react';
import DogForm from './DogForm.jsx';
import CatForm from './CatForm.jsx';
import RabbitForm from './RabbitForm.jsx';


export default class ConfigureAndLaunchContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    animal = this.props.params.animaltype;

    this.dispatcher = {
      dog : (DogForm),
      cat :(CatForm),
      rabbit :(RabbitForm),
    };
    this.formComponent = this.dispatcher[animal];
  };

  render() {
    const componentToRender = this.formComponent;

    return (
      <componentToRender app={this.props.app}/>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: React components must start with a capital letter. Try changing `componentToRender`  to `ComponentToRender`.

Comment: already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983041/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-component-based-on-a-prop-or-variable-using-react)